# Get Earliest date from from IEnumerable<DateTime>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections

I have an `IEnumerable<DateTime>` with a number of dates in it. How would I get the earliest date from that collection?

Thanks!

Dave

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this immediately with LINQ using [`Enumerable.Min`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352408.aspx).

```
DateTime minDate = dateCollection.Min();
```

Since `DateTime` implements `IComparable<DateTime>`, `Enumerable.Min` will use [`DateTime.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ata5aya.aspx) to find the minimum `DateTime` in the collection.

Answer (score 14):

```
var earliest = collection.Min();
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - I knew it was straight forward! Brain freeze today.